# Spring Data Mongo | Cannot authorize inserting into system.indexes documents without a string-typed

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing problem while trying to create Spring Data Mongo Repository.

Relevant code & config.:-

The model class:-

```
@Document(collection = "USER_DETAIL")
public class UserDetail implements
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2637223077307659181L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(dropDups = true, name = "usernameIndex", unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private List<UserRole> authorities;
    private String password;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean enabled;

        // getter & setters.
}
```

Spring Data Repository class :-

```
public interface UserDetailsRepository extends
        MongoRepository<UserDetail, String> {

    /**
     * Find a user by its username.
     * 
     * @param username
     * @return
     */
    public UserDetail findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Spring Java configuration :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "x.y.z.repository" })
public class MongoRepositoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "expunto");
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost");
        return client;
    }

}
```

Error :- **Cannot authorize inserting into system.indexes documents without a string-typed \"ns\" field." , "code" : 13 , "n" : 0 , "ok" : 1.0}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:77) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]**

Stacktrace :-

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "connectionId" : 10 , "err" : "Cannot authorize inserting into system.indexes documents without a string-typed \"ns\" field." , "code" : 13 , "n" : 0 , "ok" : 1.0}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:77) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:110) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:102) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:142) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:248) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.createIndex(DBApiLayer.java:340) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:485) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:135) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:129) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:121) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:105) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:46) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:307) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:181) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:141) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATE**:-

Spring Data Mongo version - 1.5.0.RELEASE.
Build system - Maven

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version is the MongoDB server?

Comment: @chrylis - MongoDB 2.6

Comment: Please also post the versions of the Spring Data components you're using, and how you're managing your build (Maven/Gradle?).

Comment: Version - 1.5.0.RELEASE | Maven for build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to upgrade to mongo-java-driver 2.12.1.

In Spring Data MongoDB 1.5, they switched from collection.ensureIndex to collection.createIndex.
In the 2.11.4 driver, this didn't put the default options on the index, i.e. "name" and "ns" options. This was fixed in the 2.12.1 driver.

See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1141.

Comment: You saved my day. I had the same problem with 2.4 version of mongo and the message was "invalid ns to index". Update to 2.6 led me there. Thx